# React: how to connect reusable components with usual dumb components

Tags: reactjs, components, middleware, flux

When I develop a React-based web-app, I often separate components into smart and dumb and also into reusable and custom.
Reusable components can be self-sufficient, such as e.g. `<RedButton>` or `<CustomSelect>` but they can also be middleware components, such as `<FluxStoreBinder>`. A middleware component renders its `children` while adding some functionality to them, usually such as subscribing-reading to/from a Flux store, or wrapping into some other stateful thing. However, some extra work is needed to connect a reusable smart middleware component to a dumb component because their props won't likely match. E.g. a `<FluxStoreReader>` may "return" a property named `data`, while a child of type `<ToDoList>` expects `toDoItems`.

The question which I want to ask is how to tell a middleware component which content to render in which way. What is the proper and recommended approach? Currently I've seen 3 ways of telling a middleware component how to render its children:

1. By providing a function through props, such as `render={({arg1}) => <Child prop1={arg1}/>}`. The features are: you can access own state/props/etc within this function; you can process and re-map props; you can specify which child to render depending on a condition; you can set needed props to the child without having to proxy through the middleware component.
2. By returning `React.cloneElement(children, props)` while providing a function to remap `props`.
3. By rendering `React.cloneElement(children, props)` and proxying received props down to the child. Pure component approach, no callbacks. This one don't have the features/flexibility of the above 2, and also requires some extra work: you need another middleware between your middleware and its child to re-map the props.
4. The fourth option suggested by Mike Tronic is to use higher-order components, which are basically component factories, where one of the required arguments is a child component class. It's almost the same as #3 - but you can't even change the type of the child once you've run the factory.

Which approach did you choose for your application? Why? Please share thoughts.

Would be great to hear a React guys' opinion.

Answer (score -1):

```html
check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymJOm5jY1tQ
http://rea.tech/reactjs-real-world-examples-of-higher-order-components/ and 
http://www.darul.io/post/2016-01-05_react-higher-order-components
What are Higher Order Components?
A Higher Order Component is just a React Component that wraps another one.
This pattern is usually implemented as a function, which is basically a class factory (yes, a class factory!), that has the following signature in haskell inspired pseudocode
hocFactory:: W: React.Component => E: React.Component
Where W (WrappedComponent) is the React.Component being wrapped and E (Enhanced Component) is the new, HOC, React.Component being returned.
The “wraps” part of the definition is intentionally vague because it can mean one of two things:
Props Proxy: The HOC manipulates the props being passed to the WrappedComponent W,
Inheritance Inversion: The HOC extends the WrappedComponent W.
We will explore this two patterns in more detail.
What can I do with HOCs?
At a high level HOC enables you to:
Code reuse, logic and bootstrap abstraction
Render Highjacking
State abstraction and manipulation
Props manipulation
We will see this items in more detail soon but first, we are going to study the ways of implementing HOCs because the implementation allows and restricts what you can actually do with an HOC.
```

Comment: Why would you need a class factory where a class with a parameter is enough for the task? Factories are 1) less flexible 2) less obvious when seen in the JSX tree (no explicit hierarchy).

Comment: high order functions  concept same as high order components please be sure you understand the post above. its a bit confusing if you do not understand high order functions and closure.

Comment: THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO NEED IN COMPONENT FACTORIES for the purpose of creating middleware components. Especially unless you explain it here without trashing the thread by posting youtube links. And please stop advertising your youtube channel. And please stop hypothesizing about your opponent's expertise level.